# Java problem cant find image file

Tags: java, applet

I am a student working on a homework project.  I spent DAYS trying to get the following code to display an image on my new windows 7 laptop.  I compiled it and ran it on my old xp pc and it worked!  I really want to use my laptop.  Any suggestions on how to get it to display the image? The java code. HTML and immage are all in the same sub directory on my flash drive.  I tried moving them to the c:Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_02\bin directory but it still didn't work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public  class MoveIt extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
 // set variables and componets
  private Image cup;
    Panel keypad = new Panel();
 public int top = 15;
 public int left = 15;
 private Button keysArray[];



 public void init()

 {

  cup = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "cup.gif");
  Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();

  keysArray = new Button[5];
  setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
  setBackground(Color.blue);

  // set up keypad layout
  keypad.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));

  keysArray[0] = new Button("Up");
  keysArray[1] = new Button("Left");
  keysArray[2] = new Button("Center");
  keysArray[3] = new Button("Right");
  keysArray[4] = new Button("Down");

  // add buttons to the keypad panel

  keypad.add(keysArray[0], BorderLayout.NORTH);
  keysArray[0].addActionListener(this);
  keypad.add(keysArray[1], BorderLayout.EAST);
  keysArray[1].addActionListener(this);
  keypad.add(keysArray[2], BorderLayout.CENTER);
  keysArray[2].addActionListener(this);
  keypad.add(keysArray[3], BorderLayout.WEST);
  keysArray[3].addActionListener(this);
  keypad.add(keysArray[4], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  keysArray[4].addActionListener(this);


  // add canvas and keypad to the BorderLayout
  add(myCanvas, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(keypad, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 }

 public  void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  g.drawImage( cup, left, top, this );
 }


   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
 // test for menu item clicks
  String arg = e.getActionCommand();
  if (arg == "Up")
   top -=15;
  else
   if (arg == "Down")
    top +=15;
   else
    if (arg == "Left")
     left -=15;
    else
     if (arg == "Right")
      left +=15;
     else
     {
      top = 60;
      left =125;
     }
   repaint();
   }
}
```

Comment: Tagged w/ applet as well. Are you running the Applet via AppletViewer or in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the `Applet` guy, but putting `cup.gif` alongside `MoveIt.html` and `MoveIt.class`seemed to work. Also, you're overriding the `paint()` method of `Applet`, not that of `Canvas`. As an aside, `arg == "Up"` happens to work because Java strings are [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), but `"Up".equals(arg)` is the more reliable predicate.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  There is a heck of alot more to JAVA than I realized